# Running a Django management command on Elastic Beanstalk using cron

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm running a small Django web application on Elastic Beanstalk. It uses [django-background-tasks](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks) to run some asynchronous tasks. This works locally, as I can run `python manage.py process_tasks` to run the tasks.

However, I've been having a little more trouble getting this to work as desired after deploying to Elastic Beanstalk. I managed to get it working by including this "99_process_tasks.config" file in my *.ebextensions* folder (based on this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cron-job-elastic-beanstalk/) in the AWS documentation):

```
files:
  "/etc/cron.d/process_tasks_cron":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       * * * * * root /usr/local/bin/99_process_tasks.sh

  "/usr/local/bin/99_process_tasks.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
          #!/bin/bash

      date > /tmp/date
      source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate
      cd /opt/python/current/app
      python manage.py process_tasks

commands:
  remove_old_cron:
    command: "rm -f /etc/cron.d/*.bak"
```

This worked, in that the asynchronous tasks were running and executing their code as expected.

However, as a relative novice in this field (particularly when it comes to cron) I suspect that this probably isn't doing exactly what I want, as I'm envisioning that this is causing a new `python manage.py process_tasks` command to be run every minute. What I really want to be doing is running the command just the once (or ensuring that it's run if it's no longer running). I tried using `@reboot`, which seems like it would be what I want, but when I made this change the tasks were no longer executing at all.

Is there a different cron command I should be running, or a different command entirely? Are there some additional steps I should be taking here?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: To ensure that a process is continuously running you would want to look into something like `systemd` or `supervisord` to ensure that your `99_process_tasks.sh` is constantly running.